# No carga la extencion openssl PHP 7 WAMP SERVER

Tags: php

la extencion `openssl` no carga , entre otros problemas que me causa está que no puedo acceder a contenidos en `https` con `file_get_contents` .

Ejecuto el sigiente código y me da false en openssl y wraper.

```
$w = stream_get_wrappers();
echo 'openssl: ',  extension_loaded  ('openssl') ? 'yes':'no', "<br>";
echo 'http wrapper: ', in_array('http', $w) ? 'yes':'no', "<br>";
echo 'https wrapper: ', in_array('https', $w) ? 'yes':'no', "<br>";
echo 'wrappers: ', var_export($w);
```

tengo `extension=php_openssl.dll` descomentado en  `php.ini` y `allow_url_include = On` algo más que deba hacer?

Comment: puedes mostrar el error que te sale?? asegurate de reiniciar el apache

Comment: Warning: file_get_contents(): Unable to find the wrapper "https" - did you forget to enable it when you configured PHP? in C:\wamp64\www\demails\index.php on line 11 si he reiniciado un millon de veces